# Slicing string object in Array

Tags: python, string, slice

```
def shorten_string(arr):
    newchar = []
    for char in arr:
        #for z in char:
            if char[-2:] == "Ja":
                newchar = char[0:-2]
            elif char[-4:] == "Nein":
                newchar = char[0:-4]
            newchar.append(char)
    return newchar
```

Reading an array with strings like:

```
arr = ["KK_abc_Nein","KK_abc_Ja","KK_def_Nein","KK_def_Ja"]
```

I would like to find out if the last letters match with the string object and then append the String without **_Nein** or **_Ja** to the array and return it.

```
'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

most of the time i receive this error.

Comment: You seem to be overwriting the variable `newchar` - first it's a list, and then you set it to `char[0:-2]` which is a string.

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the input you provided ? It would make it easier to understand what you want to achieve exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are currently overwriting the `newchar` list by assigning a string to it.

Instead you can use `split()`, `pop()` and `join()` to do the work:

```
def shorten_string(arr):
known_ends = ["Ja", "Nein"]
newchar = []
for char in arr:
    char = char.split("_")
    end = char.pop()
    if end in known_ends:
        newchar.append("_".join(char))
return newchar
```

This will work with any number of "words"

```
>>> arr = ["KK_abc_Nein","KK_abc_Ja","KK_def_Nein","KK_def_Ja"]
>>> shorten_string(arr)
>>> ['KK_abc', 'KK_abc', 'KK_def', 'KK_def']
```

EDIT: Added list `known_ends` to easily update the list of ends you want to process instead of overloading the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

For this example you can simply do:

```
arr = [x.replace('_Nein','').replace('_Ja','') for x in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
arr = ["KK_abc_Nein","KK_abc_Ja","KK_def_Nein","KK_def_Ja"]
b = [ s.replace('_Nein', '').replace('_Ja', '') for s in arr]
print(b)
```

will output

```
['KK_abc', 'KK_abc', 'KK_def', 'KK_def']
```